# Prob. 2 (b), Sec. 8.14, in Apostol's CALCULUS Vol 2: How to find the directional derivative of this scalar field?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be the scalar field defined by the formula 
$$ f(x, y, z) = (x/y)^z, $$
for all points $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ for which the formula makes sense.

Then what is the directional derivative of $f$ at the point $(1, 1, 1)$ in the direction of $2 \mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j} - \mathbf{k}$?

My Attempt:

> Let us put $\mathbf{a} \colon= (1, 1, 1)$ and $\mathbf{y} \colon= (2, 1, -1)$. Then $\mathbf{a} + h \mathbf{y} = ( 1 + 2h, 1 + h, 1 - h)$, and so 
>   $$
> \begin{align}
>  \frac{ f( \mathbf{a} + h \mathbf{y} ) - f( \mathbf{a} ) }{ h } &= \frac{ [ (1+2h) / ( 1+h ) ]^{1-h} - 1 }{ h } \\
> &= 
> \end{align}
> $$

What next? How to find 
$$ \lim_{ h \to 0 }  \frac{ f( \mathbf{a} + h \mathbf{y} ) - f( \mathbf{a} ) }{ h }? $$
Or, does this limit exist?

Comment: I think you need to find $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ at $(1,1,1)$, and then find the dot product of this vector with $(2,1,-1)$.

Comment: @fierydemon does this formula hold in every situation where the partials exist? According to the text by Apostol, this works only when $f$ is differentiable at $\mathbf{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have

- $f_x=\frac{z}{y}\left(\frac x y\right)^{z-1}$
- $f_y=-\frac{zx}{y^2}\left(\frac x y\right)^{z-1}$
- $f_z=\left(\frac x y\right)^{z}\log\left(\frac x y\right)$

then evaluate $\nabla f(1,1,1)$ and recall that the directional derivative along $v=2 \mathbf{i} + \mathbf{j} - \mathbf{k}$ is given by

$$f_v=\nabla f \cdot v$$

Comment: does the formula work in all cases when the partial derivatives exist? I thought it works only when the scalar field is differentiable.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmood Yes exactly we need that f is differentiable at that point

Comment: how then do we know that this particular $f$ _is_ differentiable, and at what points $(x, y, z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: At the point (1,1,1) the function is differentiable since the partial derivatives exist and are continuous at that point.